# LISP copy function

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm attempting to create a function that creates copies of whatever list the user puts in by the desired number of copies.

User: (copy '(A) '(7))
Output: (A A A A A A A)

```
(defun copy (x y)
  (cond ((-1 counter)
         nil)
        (T
         (list (cons (car x) (cdr x)))
               copy
               (cdr x)))
```

I'm attempting to set up a counter and just create a new list into the current list by decrementing the counter. So far the counter is pseudo-code.
This is the counter I'm trying to figure out.

```
(defun count (y)
  (let ((a y))
    (- a 1)))
```

The error I get is that whatever I put into `y` isn't a number.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to pass the arguments as lists when one is just an element, and the other just a number?

Comment: Is it possible to have both? Say a user wants: User: (A B C D E) and they want each element to be copied this many times (1 0 5 1 1 1). So the output would be (A B B B B B C D E).

Comment: Of course it is. :) You just need to make that requirement clear in your question. That case is not necessarily assumed by your first example.

Comment: Ya, I'm new to lisp and the best way that Ive found to tackle new material is to break the problem down one aspect of it at a time. I hate introducing an entire problem and getting a complicated answer that I cant understand =p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I can understand why the first parameter is a list, the second must be a number. A very simple implementation might look like:

```
(defun copy (lst count)
  (when (> count 0)
    (append (copy-list lst) (copy lst (1- count)))))
```

Testing:

```
CL-USER> (copy '(A) 7)
(A A A A A A A)
CL-USER>  (copy '(A B C) 7)
(A B C A B C A B C A B C A B C A B C A B C)
```

The usual caveats concerning the use of `append` and object copying apply.

Comment: Maybe the second is supposed to be similar to array dimensions?  (I doubt that was the intent, though. )

Comment: How does lisp define what will be an int and what will be a string? I'm using java talk as I am very new to lisp.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest passing your list as a `&rest` argument instead and use `loop`:

```
(defun repeat (n &rest items)
  (loop repeat n append items))
```

Test

```
CL-USER> (repeat 10 0 1 2)
(0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2)
```